# How to allow 0 but not undefined, null, '' in ternary?

Tags: typescript

let's say I have this ternary

`control.value ? null : { invalid: true };`

I want value to be valid if it's anything *BUT* `null` `undefined` and `""`

Now `0` is a valid value.

I know there is a nullish coalescing operator in typescript `??` but it is not usable in ternary.

so How would I make this line simple ? Is there a syntax better than `control.value === 0 || control.value ? null : { invalid: true };` to consider 0 as valid ?

Comment: You will have to use a logic OR specifically checking for 0 values. Something that I like to do is to have some sort of `utils.ts` and then do `Utils.isValid(value) ? 1 : 0`. Which you can keep as an exported function instead of a static field in a `Utils` class

Comment: yeah so this `control.value === 0 || control.value ? null : { invalid: true };`

Comment: Define "valid".

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps you:

```
value ? null: value === 0 ? null : { invalid: true }
```